# Exception converting Office files to PDF using ABCpdf.NET onWindows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, office-2007, xps, abcpdf

Has anyone delt with this exception from ABCpdf?  We're running on Server 2008 and only have issues converting Office files (Word and Excel).  This all worked well on Server 2003.  Because we're only having issues with Office files I wonder if it's related to the XPS support on Server 2008? The code that calls into this function is running as a Windows Service.

```
Private Overloads Function ConvertMicrosoftOfficeDocToPdf(ByVal inputFile As Byte(), ByVal fileExt As String) As Byte()
    Dim abcDoc As WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc = Nothing

    Try
        abcDoc = New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc()

        Dim xro As New WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.XReadOptions()
        xro.FileExtension = fileExt

        Try
            abcDoc.Read(inputFile, xro)
        Catch ex As Exception
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write(ex.ToString())
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Dim fileBytes As Byte() = abcDoc.GetData()
        Return fileBytes
    Finally
        If Not abcDoc Is Nothing Then
            abcDoc.Clear()
            abcDoc.Dispose()
        End If
    End Try
End Function
```

> WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Internal.PDFException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt. --->
>   System.AccessViolationException:
>   Attempted to read or write protected
>   memory. This is often an indication
>   that other memory is corrupt.
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Internal.NDoc._InvokeMethod(IntPtr
>   inDoc, Int32 inMethod, Int32 inIndex,
>   Int32 inFlags, String inParams,
>   String& outErr)
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Internal.NDoc.InvokeMethod(IntPtr
>   inDoc, Int32 inMethod, Int32 inIndex,
>   Int32 inFlags, String inParams,
>   String& outErr)
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc.PrintToXps(String
>   inputFile, String outputFile, Int32
>   timeout, String printerName)
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Operations.XpsImportOperation.ImportAny(Doc
>   doc, String path, Int32 timeout)
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.XReadOptions.ImportXpsAny(Doc
>   doc, String path, Boolean clear)
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.XReadOptions.Read(Doc
>   doc, Byte[] data, ReadModuleType
>   module)
>          at WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.XReadOptions.Read(Doc
>   doc, Byte[] data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added a folder called "Desktop" here:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/innovateonoffice/thread/b81a3c4e-62db-488b-af06-44421818ef91

Comment: Didn't work for me. Also that link is broken, so it's impossible to tell why adding that folder was even suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is that the folder where you are trying write the file, give the write permission to IIS_IUSR. Then it should work.